# easy_install pyopengl => passed, yet the module doesn't seem available

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I have installed PyOpenGL on Mac OS X 1.7.5

Installation looked like a success, yet when I try to load it, the module isn't there.

```
sudo easy_install -U PyOpenGL 

python

>>> import pyopengl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyopengl
>>> 

pip list | grep OpenGL
PyOpenGL (3.1.0a3)
```

Any leads?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need need to import from `OpenGL.GL` and from `OpenGL.GLU`. Take a look [here](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/ctypes/using.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try `import OpenGL`

```
In [1]: import OpenGL

In [2]: OpenGL.version.__version__
Out[2]: '3.1.0a1'
```